# How to use Wireless & Wired xbox 360 Pads on macos?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, macos

I have got a mac mini as multimedia and gaming station for my TV. Now i would like to play those games with my Xbox Pads, a have one wired and tree wireless pads.

I have googled it and i found some drivers to make them run under macos. But it seams just to work for the wired controllers.

What driver do you use? And do i need some additional hardware for the wireless controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of drivers out there that allow you to use an xbox controller on a mac, for example http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver. Wired controllers can just be plugged into a usb port, but to use a wireless controller, you need an [Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HZFCT2).

Comment: thank you for the link. This is the driver i have already tested. But the last update is from November 2009 an its not optimized for a 64bit os. But until i find something better i use this one. Thank you